# How to prevent a large figure occupying entire page?

Tags: graphics, floats

I have to embed a huge figure in a page where at the bottom there should be some text. However, the figure simply occupy a new page -- how to prevent this?

Comment: You may find that `[!t]`is enough to allow it to be a top float even if it breaks the constraints. Unless you mean by huge that it is actually bigger than the text area.

Comment: Related: The [excellent overview of floats](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat) by Frank Mittelbach.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is one of the possibilities suggested as use by the [`afterpage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{afterpage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage
\usepackage{float}% http://ctan.org/pkg/float
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\afterpage{%
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \rule{.8\textwidth}{.8\textheight}% Your image
    \caption{This is a HuGe figure.}
  \end{figure}
}
\lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}​
```

The use of the `H` float specifier (supported by the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float)) is crucial here and suppresses the floating. Of course, using `\captionof` (from the [`capt-of` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of)) is also a possibility.

The *default* for very large floats is to sit on a page of its own, the above circumvents that. The default is controlled by macros like `\topfraction` and `\bottomfraction`. See the [`layouts` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/layouts) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/layouts/layman.pdf) for more on this.